# Electron JS/Vue Router Packing Not Working with Electron Builder

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuejs3, electron-builder, electron-vue

Hi I have been trying to trouble shoot this problem for hours and can't figure out a solution. I created an Electron App using Vue 3 Composition and now I am trying to use Electron Builder to package it. It is not working at all, I keep getting a white screen. I tried different solutions such as:

1. setting websecurity to false
2. mainWindow.loadFile('dist/AppName/index.html') as well as many other solutions
3. adding Hash to the Vue Router.

   const router = createRouter({
   history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
   mode: 'hash',
   routes: [...

I cannot figure this out at all. I am using a Macbook M1. If more code needs to be provided let me know.

Any help would be amazing. Thank you.

Edits:

Error: "Not allowed to load local resources"

Main.js:

```
const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1080,
    height: 750,
    minWidth:1080,
    minHeight:750,
    //icon: "../src/assets/img/img/circle_logo.png",
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);

// Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "electron:start": "electron .",
    "watch:electron": "nodemon --exec electron .",
    "watch": "npm run build && concurrently \"npm run watch:electron\"",
    "start": "electron main.js",
    "package": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.myapp.app",
    "mac": {
      "target": "dmg",
      "icon": "..."
    }, 
        "files": [
        "dist"
    ]

  },
```

Another edit, I'm trying to add files:[] to the build in the package.json although it is not working. Perhaps it is the entry point? What would I put for files

Comment: Please provide your main code and check the dev console and network tab for errors.

Comment: The network tab says "not allowed to load local resources". What code do you need: package.json, main.js?

Comment: Your `main.js`, also share the exact error please, with file name, stack, line...

Comment: Done, it should show

Comment: Can you tell my what 'resource' triggers the error? Also, is `main.js` included in `dist`?

Comment: I will copy paste the error Not allowed to load local resource: file:///Volumes/MyApp%200.0.0-arm64/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/dist/index.html. And no, main.js is not in dist

Comment: Probably a problem with the path to your HTML, check what's packaged (you can disable `asar` temporarily for that) and fix the path. Also you can use `loadFile` in prod instead of `loadURL`, this way you no longer need `file://`: `mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist", "index.html"))`

Comment: Hi so I tried to fix that but still no luck. I noticed something though. I noticed the dist isn't in the app when packing so I think that's the problem. Does something need to be added to the package.json?

Comment: Ah yes, try with `files: ["./dist/**/*"]` instead of just `dist`

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you for leading me in the right direction. Heres what worked.     "directories": {
      "output": "release",
      "buildResources": "dist"
    },
    "files": [
        "**/*",
        "dist/**/*",
        "!.github",
        "!.vs",
        "!node_modules/*"
    ]

Thank you so much for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. needed to add this to package.json

```
"directories": {
  "output": "release",
  "buildResources": "dist"
},
"files": [
    "**/*",
    "dist/**/*",
    "!.github",
    "!.vs",
    "!node_modules/*"
]
```

Comment: With this config you're also including all your sources files.

Comment: How would i edit it?